# Laravel 5.1 app and home.blade.php missing

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new project via composer in *Laravel 5.1*.
I couldn't find the app.blade.php.and `home.blade.php` file, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be very useful if you could tell us what commands you used to create the project.

Comment: `home.blade.php` and other auth scaffolding stuff is not in 5.1 anymore. You have to add it manually. The app folder should exist though...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong.
The Auth Scaffolding was removed from Laravel 5.1. That includes the `app.blade.php` and the `home.blade.php` that you mentioned.

However, you'll still be able to get it back with the [Scafold Package](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold) :

1.Add Scafold to your `composer.json` file in the `require :` section :

```
require : {
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "bestmomo/scafold": "dev-master"
}
```

or type from terminal :

```
composer require bestmomo/scafold dev-master
```

2.Update composer :

```
composer update
```

3.Add the service provider to your config/app.php :

```
Bestmomo\Scafold\ScafoldServiceProvider::class,
```

4.Publish the views and assets :

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Done!

Comment: Why did they remove it??

Comment: @MicroR I think the removed it because some preferred the installation to be more barebones with less clutter/bloat, similar to comparable frameworks.

Comment: @MicroR: I definitely think they at least should have added an officially supported package or parameter to include that old rather than just removing it altogether. I ended up making a 5.0 installation and copying the files to my 5.1 app while I am learning Laravel.

Comment: @Mark, seems like the actually have, see Sambhav's answer

Comment: @chiccodoro Yup. I'm now working on a laravel 5.4 project and that is the method I use. They also have some nice documentation on setting it up

Answer (score 12):

Run `php artisan make:auth` and it will automatically generate `layoyts\app.blade.php` and `home.blade.php`

Comment: This is much simpler, and many web apps need authentication anyways, so it's no bloat. Thank you!!

Comment: In laravel 5.5 I use this command and I got all needed files. But I face the [The page has expired due to inactivity.] many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use laravel 5.0 you can download it from their repo here:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.0

And here is a video showing how to get started:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/login-with-the-built-in-laravel-5-scaffolding

Basically just

1) run `composer install` to get the dependencies then

2) run `artisan key:generate` to generate your random key for `.env` file.

3) set your database info in `.env` file

4) run `artisan migrate` to set up the database

and you should be set