# Auth resources are missing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to make use of auth system which comes with the laravel package but the problem is when I make new laravel package using composer i.e composer create-project laravel/laravel project name --prefer-dist
it do not install those auth resources which includes (i.e. auth folder inside resources > views) and also I can't find the Services Folder inside app directory.
All other things are working fine except this authentication system.
What can be the possible problems? Please give me solution
I am working with MAMP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taylor Otwell has made it [opt-in](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/578308929995816960) for Laravel 5.1

You need to run following command after installation

```
php artisan scaffold:auth
```

**UPDATE**

I think this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980906/laravel-5-1-app-and-home-blade-php-missing)

Comment: `scaffold` removed in 5.3, It should be `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 4):

You could also run the command `php artisan make:auth` in the root directory of you laravel project. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

The command `php artisan scaffold:auth` didn't work for me i don't know why.
it issued the error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
 Command "auth" is not defined.
 Did you mean this?
 make:auth
```

Answer (score 1):

in Laravel 5.2 you just have to run this command "php artisan make:auth" and the auth folder will be created

Answer (score 1):

Since laravel 6.* version `make:auth` is no longer supported, use `ui:auth` instead.

For deploying ui pack run

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

then update composer.json :

```
composer update -W
```

and do the:

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

Answer (score 0):

You need execute

```
php artisan make:auth
```

now if your style css and js are missing

You need load file .css and .js

1) execute in your project

```
npm install
```

2) then execute
`npm run dev` => now in folder /public now exist folder js and css

3) reload page