# Are there any changes in Auth blades due to four new controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3, We have four new controller.

1. LoginController
2. ForgotPasswordController
3. RegisterController
4. ResetPasswordController

Is there any update about any new blades for them? or the blades can still be used **[as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980906/laravel-5-1-app-and-home-blade-php-missing)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates these views:

```
'auth/login.blade.php',
'auth/register.blade.php',
'auth/passwords/email.blade.php',
'auth/passwords/reset.blade.php',
'layouts/app.blade.php',
'home.blade.php'
```

And modify these files:

```
'Http/Controllers/HomeController.php', 
'routes/web.php'
```

If called with the --views parameter it just creates the views

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/MakeAuthCommand.php)

Answer (score 0):

Default Auth scaffolding is back, so if you're starting a new project you don't need to add an external package like "bestmomo/scafold" anymore.

just run `php artisan make:auth` after initial setup and you'll get the new "default" authentication structure.

If you need a more featured one I suggest you [laravel sparks](https://spark.laravel.com/) (official 99$) or [laracogs](https://laracogs.com/docs/Kits/starter/) (free)

Anyway blades could still be used "[as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980906/laravel-5-1-app-and-home-blade-php-missing)" but the new default approach is different.

Check also why did they choose to integrate [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) by default as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases#laravel-5.3) at chapter "Frontend Structure" that also has this [video link](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/4) explanation

Comment: which files will be impacted after running this `php artisan make:auth`